# Android Architecture Components : How to observe single changes in the database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a few questions, please see questions below :

**The Code**.

**DAO**

```
@Dao
    public interface PostDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by time DESC")
        LiveData<List<StoryPost>> getAll();

        @Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id")
        LiveData<List<StoryPost>> getPost(String id);

        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        @NonNull
        void insert(StoryPost... posts);

        @Delete
        void delete(StoryPost post);

        @Update
        void update(StoryPost post);
    }
```

**Db**

```
@Database(entities = {StoryPost.class}, version = 5)
    @TypeConverters(Conveter.class)
    public static abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

        static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = db(context);
            }
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        public abstract PostDao postDAO();
    }
```

**ModelView**

```
public static class PostsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        private final mLiveData data;

        public PostsViewModel(Application application) {
            super(application);
            data = new mLiveData(application);
        }

        public LiveData<List<StoryPost>> getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void delete(StoryPost post) {
            AsyncTask.execute(() -> db(getApplication()).postDAO().delete(post));
        }
    }
```

**Entity (Kotlin)**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
@Entity(tableName = "posts")
class StoryPost : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String? = null
    var time: Long = 0

    var story: StoryPojo? = null

    @Embedded
    var user: User? = null

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**LiveData**

```
public static class mLiveData extends LiveData<List<StoryPost>> {
        private final Context context;

        public mLiveData(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            loadData();
        }

        private void loadData() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActive() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onInactive() {
        }
    }
```

**Question 1 :**

With the above code, my understanding is that I should observe the data as followes using the `viewModel`. I want to use the ViewModel, but I'm not getting any data while 'observing', how can I fix this ?

```
PostsViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostsViewModel.class);
        model.getData().observe(this, data -> {
            adapter.addList(data);
        });
```

But that doesn't return any data, while the following works well :

```
LiveData<List<StoryPost>> liveData = postDAO(context).getAll();
            AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
                liveData.observeForever(storyPosts -> postValue(storyPosts));
            });
```

**Question 2 :**

If i were using this :

```
LiveData<List<StoryPost>> liveData = postDAO(context).getAll();
                AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
                    liveData.observeForever(storyPosts -> postValue(storyPosts));
                });
```

How can I observe single changes in the database, like when a row is removed or new row added?

Comment: Question 1 is not a question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I'll do better next time, for now. in question 1, i want to use the ViewModel, but I'm not getting any data while 'observing', how can I fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to ask that. I have not had a chance to play with this new library, so I cannot answer your question. I am trying to help you improve it so that you have more chances of attracting others who have more knowledge than I.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, ok thanks, editted.

Comment: It might also help if you provide more complete code under your question headings. In particular, show the lines of code inside a method in a class.